# Login by Sending Paramters (Credentials) in the Request

Tags: java, tomcat, ldap, jmeter

I have implemented Active Directory LDAP server authentication for an application in Tomcat. The Authentication works but I also have another requirement where I need to use a special authentication, for example an Admin user, who doesn't need to use the portal to gain access to a particular page.

For Instance, he could use the below URL to access page 10

```
http://myhost:8080/index.jsp?page=10&j_username=admin&j_password=Password
```

The reason behind this unusual way of access is, the Admin would like to trigger some functionality (DB reload) through scripts that run in production. So basically when you access this URL, the database will be reloaded.

I would like to know how I can implement this, since right now If i use the above URL I just reach the Login page. How can I pass in the Admin credentials and access the page 10 ?

I was able to achieve the same when we didn't have Active Directory (AD) LDAP authentication, we basically hardcoded the admin credentials and cross checked it when the user logged in, well this is a very old application. Now we don't want to hardcode any credentials and moved to AD LDAP, but we stumbled into this problem of not able to access a particular page, our Jmeter scripts also stopped working after this change.

Please help me with your suggestions or example implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are looking for, you need to implement [form based authentication within Tomcat.](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-form-authentication-with-tomcat.html)

The link should help.